# ruby / rails ordering of result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to produce a high score chart, with a list of users who have been given a "thumbs" ordered by the number of thumbs descending. I have it almost working, but cannot think how to get the records to order correctly.

So we have two models, being User and Thumb.

In the controller, we have

```
def thumbs_highscores
  user_ids = current_account.thumbs.from_this_month.map(&:user_id)
  @users = current_account.users.where(:id =>emp_ids)
end
```

In the view I am then displaying the high scores likes this...

```
%table.center{:style => "max-width: 600px"}
  %tr
    %th Rank
    %th Name
    %th.right # Thumbs received
  - @users.each_with_index do |user, i|
    %tr
    %td= i+1 
    %td= user.name
    %td.right 
      - user.thumbs.from_this_month.each do |thumb|
        %i.fa.fa-star.orange
```

This works nicely, but is not displaying the users in the correct order. I would like to amend the controller code to list the users in the order of how many thumbs they have had in the last month but cannot get my head round it. Can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: Am i right in thinking that if a user has 10 thumbs from the last month you want to show 10 `%i.fa.fa-star.orange` tags next to them?  If that's the case then you don't need to load the thumbs themselves, you just need to know the number?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
@users.each_with_index do |user, i|
```

to

```
@users.sort_by{|u| u.thumbs_from_this_month.size}.reverse.each_with_index do |user, i|
```

You could eager load the thumbs associations in the controller to make this more efficient, and do the ordering there.

Comment: You could eager load the thumbs associations in the controller to make this more efficient, and do the ordering there. - could you please explain how - I'm pretty new to this :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the help of [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) here. I'm not very skilled with lambdas, but I guess something like this in the **user-model** would work:

```
scope :thumbs_desc_list, lambda { User.all.map {|u| u.thumbs_this_month}.sort { |x,y| y <=> x } }
```

This ofcourse assumes you have an instance method in your user-model called `thumbs_this_month` which gives you the amount of thumbs received this month.

After that in the **controller**:

```
@users = User.thumbs_desc_list
```

... and now you should be able to iterate over `@users` in your view wherever you want, having them ordered by thumbs amount descendingly.

Using scope will allow you to use the properly order list wherever you need afterwards too.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your code you should have a scope named `from_this_month` so my suggestion is to add order in the query, so you don't need to care about extra code and complexity to order your data.

Check the [order documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code into below:

```
User.select("users.*, thumbs.*, count(thumbs.id) AS thumbs_count").joins(:thumbs).from_this_month.group("users.id").order("thumbs_count DESC")
```

Let me know when it works.

Comment: How about efficiency? Joins, yes, uses lazy loading, but this query still hits the thumbs-table with query also- am I right? If that's the case, then I'd prefer a way, where you just count the thumbs on an user-object. Thatway you'll save some additional unnecessary querys and therefore time.

Comment: Andres Ehrenpreis. Sometimes we needs join table as ruby on rails uses in has-many associations. For examples: current_user.thumbs, it means that User joins Thumb table. If you want to select only column that you want, it's good way. For instance:  User.select("users.id, users.name, count(thumbs.id) AS thumbs_count").joins(:thumbs).from_this_month.group("users.id").order("thumbs_count DESC")